# Multiselect checkbox: Sending parameters only for element that has been changed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, checkbox, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using `bootstrap-multiselect-rails` gem with rails `select`. When I am unchecking a previously checked item the item is not being sent. But, I need this status change to be sent, otherwise I'll have no clue which entries to remove from database.

Consider a scenario where,

- each selection item correspond to a database table row.
- If an item is selected, and request posted, row will be added, and,
- if the item is unchecked, and request posted row will be removed.

So, I need to send two things as parameters
 - **selection status** of **only the items that has been changed**.
I need to prevent sending those parameters that belongs to elements that has not been changed.

Comment: You need to do this control yourself. Save selected items before the changes and compare with selected items after the changes. This way you can get what was included and what was excluded.